# Converting a Shell Script Into a *.app File

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, executable, desktop

Using Automator.app and Platypus.app, I have been able to bundle a simple shell script I created to power cycle wi-fi on my MacBook Pro.  Both resulting apps run properly, but have one glaring issue that I want to correct:  The apps reference the shell script from outside of the program.  How can I embed the shell script and reference it from the app's resources so that the app can run even if the original source file is moved?

Comment: cross ref; https://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus I love Platypus!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just to mention it, if you Get Info on a script, you can set it to be opened with the Terminal. This will run the script when you double-click it.

Otherwise, packaging a script in a .app bundle is trivial. Mac OS X will happily run any script identified as the application's executable.

At a minimum, you need to following structure in place:

- (name).app

  - Contents

    - MacOS

      - (name)

Where the file called (name) is your script (which **must** be executable, and **must** have a shebang line). (name) must be identical in the .app directory and the script file: for instance, if your app directory is called "My Shell Script.app", then the file inside the MacOS directory must be called "My Shell Script", with **no extension**.

If this is inconvenient, it's possible to use an Info.plist file to specify an alternate executable name. The Info.plist goes in the Contents directory:

- Wrapper.app

  - Contents

    - Info.plist
    - MacOS

      - MyScript

This structure (a MyScript executable in a wrapper called Wrapper.app) works if you specify MyScript as the `CFBundleExecutable` in the property list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MyScript</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Using an Info.plist file is probably preferable, as that will allow you to rename your wrapper without breaking it.

Here's one example script that uses `/bin/sh` as the interpreter, but you really could have anything (`#!/usr/bin/swift`, `#!/usr/bin/python`, etc).

```
#!/bin/sh
open -a Calculator
```

The script will run as you double-click the app bundle.

You can bundle anything else that you need with your script within the `Contents` directory. If you feel fancy, you can reproduce the standard executable bundle layout with a `Resources` directory and things like that.

Comment: Isn't this file structure considered a PowerPC application?  If so, they haven't been supported since 10.7 was released.

Comment: As far as I know, the application's architecture has always been identified by executable headers, not by the bundle's structure, and PPC support was dropped at 10.6, without altering any of this. Either way, this works perfectly fine on my Yosemite setup, if you're worried.

Comment: This was the first solution I tried.  http://goo.gl/GgqaR6 shows the directory structure, the way the app icon is crossed out, and the error message when I try to run it.  Unless I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: What format is your cyclewifi file? At 391K, it's a bit on the heavy side for a shell script. (Also, I just re-did exactly what I explained here and it worked, so I'm not sure what's the problem here.)

Comment: networksetup -setairportpower en1 off;
sleep 5;
networksetup -setairportpower en1 on;

There used to be a killAll Terminal command at one point, too.

Comment: That's hardly 391K. Is that all you have in there? Have you considered writing a new script from scratch with just that and the shebang line?

Comment: After reviewing my file structure, ≈300k was added because of a custom icon.  The wrapper.app became viable as soon as I added the shebang to the myscript file.  Without the shebang, the app registered to the os as a powerpc application.

Comment: Unfortunately when you copy the app to another Mac the execution permissions are lost and nothing happens. Is there a solution for that too?

Comment: @nepa, what about fixing the execution permissions with chmod?

Comment: Though this works; I just want to note that you cannot code sign the bundle with the script in MacOS. Code signatures are not maintained for non-Mach-O files in the MacOS directory. See Apple's Code Signing Guide with more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW7

Comment: What exactly happens when I try to open a file using an app like this? Is there a way to give the file to the shell script as argument?

Comment: @Daniel, if I’m not mistaken, macOS uses Apple Events to tell your program to open a document. You won’t be able to receive those from a shell script. It might be possible from scripting languages that can access native libraries.

Comment: How can we make the app interact with `stdin` and `stdout`? For example, if the script were simply to read two numbers and print the result of adding them, the app does nothing. How to fix this?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe, macOS does not connect your app to a tty when you start it by double-clicking it. Stdout goes to the Console app, and I think that stdin is unconnected. You need to find another way to ask for input values or print output. AppleScript/Automator could be better choices for you, or you can write a smaller program that brings up a GUI window with a text field for input and use that from your shell script.

Comment: Big Sur: I had to change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` in order to prevent the .app from continuously asking for Input Permissions.

Comment: @zneak thanks! Works on Big Sur, however, after moving the .app into /Applications, executing it using Spotlight behaves strange: I have to hit Enter twice, and Spotlight categorizes it under "Applications" (instead of no category at all). Do you know what it needs to make Spotlight recognize my .app as a "real" app? It seems some part is missing. I tried the Info.plist as well -> no success.

Answer (score 0):

While this works, there seems to be no way to access the Contents directory from the script. Its not passed in the environment variables to bash, or anywhere else I can find. This makes it hard to bundle stuff into the Contents directory since it seems to be inaccessible by the bash script. There are various hacks on the net, but they all involve effectively searching for the script by name, which means if there are two versions of the app in two places then it will fail. 
Anyone solve that?

Comment: What is the value of "$0" in the bash script? If it contains the full path, you could use `dirname` to get to the Contents folder.

Comment: I got it working with ```$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)```