# Notorize .app with a Shell Script Main Executable

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW7) on "What to Code Sign", shell scripts are not 'code', and are therefore a resource. It goes on to say about shell scripts "While it's possible to sign such executables and store them in Contents/MacOS, this is not recommended."

My question is, what should I do if my app's main executable IS a shell script? I tried putting my script into /Resources and added a symlink in MacOS, but I got `the main executable or Info.plist must be a regular file (no symlinks, etc.)` Do I need to do something drastic like port the entire shell script to C?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to consider why do you want to notarize your script.
Notarization is an Apple servers-side verification, that you are a certified developer with some name, and it is really you, who signed some bundle.

This is needed only if you want to distribute your app to other users, and I would say in your case it is only appropriate if you want to distribute this in appstore, because otherwise you could just post a script and let your users to download it and run.

If you are shure you need this and want to distribute script as an application, try this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792824/2869674)

TLDR: place script named without any extension into MyBundle.app/Contents/MacOS and add into Info.plist the CFBundleExecutable key with script name in value.

After that, code signing and notarization should be the same as for any other bundle.

Comment: That is how I have it already, my concern is that it doesn't conform to the guidelines and could be rejected.

Comment: The only way to know it is to try it. You can try to notarize the app many times, errors are common during this process. If it would be rejected because of script in Contents/MacOS, you could always create a C program with just one line calling your script from bundle resources - this should be definetely ok.

Comment: It won't be rejected by notarization alone because of a script in `Contents/MacOS`, this is fairly common practice (I do this for a notarized app myself), however if the app is Sandboxed, the script will show as "Sandboxed: No" in Activity Monitor (the main executable will show as "Sandboxed: Yes") since you can't add these entitlements to a script file.  I'm uncertain if this will raise any red flags in the notarization/approval process.