# How to sign a shell script to run on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, shell, security, sign

I try to create a simple shell script name `test.command` with the following content

```sh
echo 'hello world'
```

When I send the script to another user via slack and he will find that he is not able to run it by double click the script without allowing it in the system's security setting.

I know that Apple requires apps download from the internet to be signed and notarize to avoid the security alert. But how to sign and notarize a single shell script?

Comment: Typically, one just runs a shell script from the terminal rather than via the Finder.

Comment: Well, that's true for developer. But mine is to provide a solution for the normal end users to run it by just double click the download file.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to distribute this solution, you should either [pack this script into a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67291774/2869674), and then sign it
or rewrite the logic into a program on c/objc/swift/etc, also pack it into a bundle, and sign it.

Comment: Yes. I am wondering if there are tools can help to make it easier?

Comment: There are some tools that does bundling for you, but I am not aware of what are up to date:
https://github.com/ProgramYazar/MacBundleCreator
http://shoplist.dedasys.com/makeBundle/